# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException while adding item to a list

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to make a desktop app with Netbeans and the model-control-view pattern for my programming exam. I have to manage a bed and breakfast and I'm having problems adding a room to the archive (I'm using a mock Dao) (i'm also translating the code to english to make you understand better, so i'm sorry if i forget some words or some words are incorrect)

```
public class ControlDialogAddRoom {

    private Action actionAddRoom = new ActionAddRoom();


    public Action getActionAddRoom() {
        return actionAddRoom;
    }

 private class ActionAddRoom extends AbstractAction{

        public ActionAddRoom (){
            this.putValue(Action.NAME, "Add room");
            this.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Add a room");
        }
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Bed bed= (Bed)Application.getInstance().getModel().getBean(Constants.BED);

                Room roomAdded = checkFields(bed);
                if(roomAdded != null){
                    //i wrote this just to make sure that the program was getting the right text from the fields
                    System.out.println(roomAdded.toString());
                    bed.addRoom(roomAdded);
                    Application.getInstance().getFrame().showInfo("Room correctly added!");
                    Applicazione.getInstance().getDialogRoomAdded().initFields();
                }

            }
```

Now i'll paste the checkField method. name and code are two JTextFields, price and numberOfBeds are two JSpinner. the Jspinner field for the price also gives me some errors if i leave the default number 1.

```
private Room checkFields(Bed){
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
            String roomCode = Application.getInstance().getDialogAddRoom().getFieldCode();
            String roomName = Application.getInstance().getDialogAddRoom().getFieldName();
            float price= (Float)Application.getInstance().getDialogAddRoom().getSpinnerPrice();
            int numberOfBeds = (Integer)Application.getInstance().getDialogAddRoom().getSpinnerNumberOfBeds();
            if(roomCode.isEmpty()){
                errors.append("\nThe code cant be empty");
            }
            for(Room room : bed.getRooms()){
                if(room.getCode().equals(roomCode)){
                    errors.append("\nThere's already a room with that code");
                }
            }            
            if(roomName.isEmpty()){
                errors.append("\nThe field name can't be empty");
            }                    
            if(!(errors.toString()).isEmpty()){

          Application.getInstance().getFrame().showErrors(errors.toString());
                return null;
            }
            return new Room(roomName, roomCode, numberOfBeds, price);
        }
```

the error of the price:

```
          Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
```

The main error tho is in the line of code 
`bed.addRoom(roomAdded);`

in the Bed class this is a simple method that worked a lot of other times to me. i have a list of rooms and i simply add a new room:

```
 private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

public void addRoom(Room room){
        this.rooms.add(room);
    }
```

I get the following stack on the output

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at it.unibas.bedandbreakfast.model.Bed.addRoom(Sistema.java:27)
    at it.unibas.bedandbreakfast.control.ControlDialogAddRoom$ActionAddRoom.actionPerformed(ControlDialogAddRoom.java:51)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at it.unibas.bedandbreakfast.view.DialogAddRoom.showWindow(DialogAddRoom.java:151)
    at it.unibas.bedandbreakfast.control.ControlPanelMenu$ActionAddRoom.actionPerformed(ControlPanelMenu.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

i really don't understand what's wrong??? i'm just almost sure the problem is with the line of code `bed.addRoom(roomAdded);`

**EDIT:**
I've modified some lines in the Action and now it works, but I'd still like to know what i was doing wrong before. I've added this

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Bed bed= (Bed)Application.getInstance().getModel().getBean(Constants.BED);

            //ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE            
            List<Room> allTheRooms = new ArrayList<>(bed.getRooms());

            Room roomAdded = checkFields(bed);
            if(roomAdded != null){
                   System.out.println(roomAdded.toString());

                   //ADDED THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES
                    allTheRooms.add(addedRoom);
                    bed.setRooms(allTheRooms);

                    Application.getInstance().getFrame().showInfo("Room correctly added!");
```

like the user @xerx593 said in the comments, it's like the type information got lost

Comment: For the price, is it ok? If not, just make a Integer.Parse()

Comment: The `UnsupportedOperationException` comes from `AbstractList.add()`, no doubts! But *why* is it `AbstractList` although you declare it as `ArrayList`?? ..i assume "the problem" most likely in: `Bed bed= (Bed)Application.getInstance().getModel().getBean(Constants.BED);` ..somehow  the type information for the list goes lost.